# Advanced python string search

Tags: python, search

I was wondering if anyone can point me to a library that can search a string using google-ish syntax. Examples:

[Google advanced search syntax](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=136861)

[Craigslist advanced search syntax](http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/search)

So if the query were

> food -pizza

and the search subject was

> Ray's Pizza, best food in town!

It would not result in a match. Etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home) is really great fast, full-text search engine written in Python, it has a nice API and nice documentation.

Comment: Thanks, you know of any tutorials by chance?

Comment: The docs are pretty good and have a lot of examples. There is also this tutorial geared towards use with Django: http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/add-full-text-search-to-your-django-project-with-whoosh.html. If you are familiar with Django, looking at [Haystack's](http://haystacksearch.org/) source would give you a good idea what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it has to be Python?  Because Lucene would be perfect otherwise.

Comment: Did you mean to answer "PyLucene" instead?

Comment: Pure python would be preferred.